# How to align 3 pictures perfect horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a main page with three colors each divided in 1/3 of the page and each in the color must be a centered picture which will flip when hovering over it. I can't manage the align the three pictures perfectly apart from eachother but also centered in every color side.

```css
    body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/backgroundIndex.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.indexLogo{
    width: 100%;
}

.indexLogoImg{
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}

#f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 8%;
    float:left;
}
#f1_container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Uitgaanscentrum De Bonte Koe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Uitgaanscentrum De Bonte Koe door Mustafa Tosuncu en Alperen Yavuz">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Mustafa, Tosuncu, Mustafa, Tosuncu, Website, ALA, De, Bonte, Koe, Alperen, Yavuz">
    <meta name="author" content="Mustafa Tosuncu">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="indexLogo"><img class="indexLogoImg" src="img/logo.png"/></header>
    <div id="f1_container">
        <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
            <div class="front face">
                <img src="http://www.startpagina.nl/athene/dochters/rimini/images/party_time-1280x800.jpg" width="200" height="120"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><div class="back face center">
                    <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
                    <p>Any content can go here.</p>
                </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="f1_container">
        <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
            <div class="front face">
                <img src="http://www.restauranthoteldelakei.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/restaurant.jpeg" width="200" height="120"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><div class="back face center">
                    <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
                    <p>Any content can go here.</p>
                </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="f1_container">
        <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
            <div class="front face">
                <img src="http://emmaseetcafe.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Cinema.jpg" width="200" height="120"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><div class="back face center">
                    <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
                    <p>Any content can go here.</p>
                </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using the same ID name on more than one element. This should be done with classes in  oppose to ID's as an ID should be unique to that individual element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this css given below;

```
  .f1_container {
         float:left;
         width:33.33%
    }
```

Comment: I will try that in two hours but ill doubt it because the div already has its eitdh and height for the pictures

Comment: bro!! you should try... if something wrong tell me here !!! i have one more solution!! or you can send me link here please

Comment: It doesn't work, it changes the size of the picture.

Comment: #f1_container {width:33.33%; text-align :center; } and remove the padding from both side! and .front img {width:100%}

Comment: Doesn't work because the width of the f1_container is the width of the pictures

Comment: i am not getting you!! can you explain again??

Comment: Nevermind, it worked I just did it in a seperate class. Thanks!